# wp_query - Modify $query to include duplicate content

Tags: wp-query, query, array, pre-get-posts, theme-customizer

I'm setting  some featured content through the customizer
(it's saved in theme_mod);

Using the `pre_get_posts` hook, I'm retireving the feature pages in this way:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');

function alter_query($query){    
 $foo = array('one'   => get_theme_mod("featured_content_one", "default_value" ),
              'two'   => get_theme_mod("featured_content_two", "default_value" ),
              'three' => get_theme_mod("featured_content_three", "default_value" ),
              'four'  => get_theme_mod("featured_content_four", "default_value" ),
);

        if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type',  'page'  );
        $query->set ('post__in', $foo ) ;

    }
}
```

Currently I'm retrieving the content but the $query object post__in property won't allow duplicate content( and I need it for structure markup..).

The problem is I can't find a property that accepts my array of page ids and (possibly) outputs this array keeping the input order.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is meant for altering the query, but not in the way you're attempting. you might want to use the `the_content` filter, checking for `is_main_query()` and `is_front_page()` etc

Comment: I can pick up posts through `$query->set('post__in', array(12,16))` but I haven't found a working argument for pages.. could you explain why  `pre_get_posts` is no good , does it depend from the post-type?

Comment: ah, I think I misunderstood your intention based on the format of your `$foo` array. have you tried using passing an array of page ids to `post__in`?